# Create OBIEE Go URL client using JAVA

Tags: java, httpclient, obiee

I am developing a JAVA application which will fetch and save OBIEE dashboards as PDF with some parameters in local file system. I understand that it is achievable using [GO URL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/bi.1111/e16364/apiwebintegrate.htm#BIEIT353)

Example:

https://aaaa:yyyy/analytics/saw.dll?Dashboard&NQUser=AAAA&NQPassword=BBBB&Action=Print&PortalPath=%2Fshared%2FTest%2F_portal%2FPopulation&Page=India&Format=pdf&P0=3&P1=eq&P2=%22Current%20Date%22.%22Year%20%28yyyy%29%22&P3=2016&P4=eq&P5=%22Current%20Date%22.%22Calendar%20Month%22&P6=%22August%22&P7=eq&P8=%22Client%22.%22Parent%20Region%20Name%22&P9=%22India%22

However, unfortunately, I am unable to create HTTP client to display PDF results. GET or POST request s are displaying response as HTML with content of signing in in page.

If I use the same URL in the browser then it works fine and display PDF report. I observed that when I copy past this URL in browser and press enter then the request header sends below cookies a part of request

ORA_BIPS_LBINFO=15aa813ce2f; ORA_BIPS_NQID=ftlv6jn555550h7l1jv4sbhhhhhh2d2710d0qc5epunh9pi8b7jkb;

I am clue less from where request is getting these cookies? I am sending credentials a part of request.

Please help to provide sample code to implement this requirement.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ankit, you will need to establish a secure session in order to get cookies. You can only establish a secure session within a browser that supports the encryption method being used. You need to emulate a browser in your Java code. Reference here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250674/is-there-any-tool-to-simulate-http-requests-in-java. You can use Apache commons Httpclient: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/

Comment: I tried creating a POST request with below request headers but still getting the same signing in page POST /analytics/saw.dll?Dashboard HTTP/1.1
Host: aaaa:yyyy
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: same URL